# Unity3D - (Incredibly Basic) Can Jump all directions except for North-East

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Player's movement is incredibly basic `Input.GetAxisRaw` movement. I got my current jumping system from this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc). I made sure to understand the code before typing it out myself.
Either way, this problem exists with every other jumping method I've implemented. I think it might have something to do with the values given with the `W` and `D` keys. Maybe a positive value on each axis overrides the ability to jump?

Here is the relevant code from my `Player` game object.

Starting with the variables:

```
    public float speed;
    public float gravity;
    public float jumpHeight = 3.0f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 velocity;
```

```
private void Move() {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

         if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        Jump();
    }

    private void Jump() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && isGrounded) {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        //This was my attempt at brute forcing the diagonal jump...didn't even run the Debug.Log().
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && isGrounded) { 

            Debug.Log("Moving Diagonal and attempting to jump");
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        //=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

I know that there are a **lot** of amateur Unity questions on the Internet, but I haven't found a solution for my specific one. Sure, there are "Can't jump diagonally in general" issues, but not "Can't jump diagonally *in one specific direction*" issues.

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Possible that it is a hardware limitation. Its a longstanding web game issue that "up, left, space" was a three-key combination that just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is that **isGrounded** is never set true.

`isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);`
The following code requires the groundDistance to be greater or equal to the distance your groundCheck center position. This is because `groundCheck.position` does not take into account render bounds.

While you might think

```
     if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }
```

is being called, the `CharacterController` component adds gravity without using Rigidbody
physics.

Here is the code I tested. Everything worked as expected:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterControllerInputDemo : MonoBehaviour
 {
public float speed =3;
public float gravity= -9;
public float jumpHeight = 3.0f;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundDistance =  1.5f;
public LayerMask groundMask;
//To view in the inspector for debugging
[SerializeField] bool isGrounded;
// allow assignment in the editor
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 velocity;

void Start()
{
    if(controller == null)
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
private void Move()
{

    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    Jump();
}

private void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }


    //=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/=/
    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}
}
```